# Transform For loop into while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
s=0

for i in range(3,20,2):
    if i>10:
        break
    else:
        s=s+i
    
print(s)
```

how can i transform this code into a while loop?

I don't know how to include the step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to break the loop when i>10, then why you're running the loop till 20? Any way you can try this

```
s,i=0,3
while i<=20:
    if i>10:
        break
    else:
        s=s+i
    i+=2
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 0
i = 3
while i<10:
    s+=i
    i+=2
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can transform the for loop into a while loop:

```
s = 0
i = 3
while i < 20:
    if i > 10:
        break
    else:
        s = s + i
    i += 2
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent something when you could do this using a `range` and the `sum` functions:

```
>>> sum(range(3,10, 2))
24
```